# Why does my Ethernet adapter have two devices?

Tags: ethernet

My laptop has a single Ethernet port and a Realtek Ethernet controller:

```
$ ip -brief addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp2s0f0         DOWN           
enp5s0           UP             192.168.50.83/24 fe80::3af3:abff:fe0c:886f/64 
wlp3s0           UP             192.168.50.127/24 fe80::6dc5:4c36:33c3:2795/64

$ lspci | grep -i ethernet
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

What confuses me is that I got two Ethernet devices: enp2s0f0 (down) and enp5s0 (up). I've been trying to figure out why this is. My best guess is that this is the result of a firmware update (because the rev numbers are different) but I suspect there's something quite basic I don't quite understand.

The laptop is a Thinkpad P14S running AlmaLinux 9.

### Update

The laptop is sometimes connected to a docking station. Here's the `ip addr` output when it's connected to the dock:

```
$ ip -brief addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp2s0f0         DOWN           
enp5s0           DOWN           
wlp3s0           UP             192.168.50.127/24 fe80::6dc5:4c36:33c3:2795/64 
enp7s0f3u1u1     UP             192.168.50.121/24 fe80::e9ba:6cf3:d104:781/64

$ lspci | grep -i ethernet
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

# lshw -class network -short
H/W path                  Device          Class          Description
====================================================================
/0/100/2.2/0              enp2s0f0        network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
/0/100/2.3/0              wlp3s0          network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/2.6/0              enp5s0          network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
/c                        enp7s0f3u1u1    network        Ethernet interface
```

And this is the output of `lspci -t`:

```
# lspci -t
-[0000:00]-+-00.0
           +-00.2
           +-01.0
           +-02.0
           +-02.1-[01]----00.0
           +-02.2-[02]--+-00.0
           |            +-00.1
           |            +-00.2
           |            +-00.3
           |            \-00.4
           +-02.3-[03]----00.0
           +-02.4-[04]----00.0
           +-02.6-[05]----00.0
           +-02.7-[06]----00.0
           +-08.0
           +-08.1-[07]--+-00.0
           |            +-00.1
           |            +-00.2
           |            +-00.3
           |            +-00.4
           |            +-00.5
           |            \-00.6
           +-14.0
           +-14.3
           +-18.0
           +-18.1
           +-18.2
           +-18.3
           +-18.4
           +-18.5
           +-18.6
           \-18.7
```

### Another update

This might be more readable:

````
# lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
           +-00.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
           +-01.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
           +-02.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
           +-02.1-[01]----00.0  SK hynix Gold P31 SSD
           +-02.2-[02]--+-00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           |            +-00.1  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #1
           |            +-00.2  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #2
           |            +-00.3  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP IPMI interface
           |            \-00.4  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL811x EHCI host controller
           +-02.3-[03]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200
           +-02.4-[04]----00.0  Genesys Logic, Inc GL9750 SD Host Controller
           +-02.6-[05]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-02.7-[06]----00.0  Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller
           +-08.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
           +-08.1-[07]--+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir
           |            +-00.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
           |            +-00.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
           |            +-00.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
           |            +-00.4  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
           |            +-00.5  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
           |            \-00.6  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
           +-14.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller
           +-14.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge
           +-18.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
           +-18.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
           +-18.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
           +-18.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
           +-18.4  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
           +-18.5  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
           +-18.6  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
           \-18.7  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7```
````

Comment: You seem to have two physical LAN cards. No idea how and why.

Comment: yep, these are on two different PCIe bus addresses, and have different revisions.

Comment: do you by chance have a docking station? can you add the full output of `lspci -t` to your question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - yes, it's sometimes connected to a docking station (though not when I looked at the `ip addr` output). I've added the output of `lspci -t` to my question.

Comment: is that `lspci -t` with, or without the dock connected?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That is with the dock connected.

Comment: can you save the output of `lspci` to a file (`lspci > filename_with`) with and without the dock, and compare the two, e.g. using `diff filename_with filename_without_dock`

Comment: The output files are identical, both for `lspci` and `lspci -tv` (tested twice just to be sure).

I think it's something to do with the laptop model. I just checked the output of `ip addr` on an identical P14S and the output is the same - and that laptop has never been connected to a docking station.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Archlinux Wikipage:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T14_(AMD)_Gen_2

```
enp5s0 is the RJ45 port. enp2s0f0 is the proprietary connector next to the 2nd USB Type-C port for use in the Lenovo ThinkPad Ultra Docking Station or with a Lenovo ThinkPad Ethernet Extension Cable Gen 2 cable.
```

Your Dockings Station seems to be a USB-C Docking station